# Scan through wifi with mx870 printer

Tags: 16.04, wireless, canon, scanner, pixma

I just installed my canon mx870 printer through wifi like this:

1. Connecting printer to router (my modem) using WPS.
2. Under 16.04 (Unity Desktop at the time. Now I use XFCE but setup didn't change) I followed [this procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu#Printing_from_Ubuntu) (I typed "mx870" instead of ip).

Wifi printing worked like a charm, but I was unable to scan (while when printer is connected to my computer through usb port scan works perfectly). The error message goes like this:

"Failed to Scan. Unable to connect to scanner".

Yet as per the [documentation](http://canoncanada.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18986/~/pixma-mx870-wireless-assistance) the printer should be able to scan through wifi..

Any idea ?

Comment: For scanning you'll probably need to use the USB connection. Wireless scanning is probably only for Mac/Windows environments.

Comment: How comes? I mean what is the cause of this impossibility?

Comment: You might look at http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/08/14/canon-printer-driver-scangear-mp-ubuntu-16-04/ and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/sane-pixma.5.html

Comment: Yes, you can print wi-fi, as networked printers are fairly common. Networked scanners less so. Did you check the two links I provided for you? They may help you find a way to do it.

Comment: I already have libsane-common installed by default. Which is supposed as per your 2d link to be a "backend that implements both the USB interface  and  network  interface". The latter supporting "scanners over IPv4 as well as IPv6e".

Comment: I don't have any more answers for you. Sorry. Hopefully somebody else can chime in... or your Google searches may.

Comment: Google search taught me that libsane-common is the documentation that provided the content of your second link, it doesn't contain any driver. Nevertheless sane-pixma is already on my system through libsane-pixma.so. I guess it is used when I scan through usb but I don't know how to verify this. The first link you sent, I don't understand, it seems to be procedures to install some other drivers but it doesn't explain anything .

Comment: It seems that sane-pixma only support USB and ethernet interfaces: http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON